# div Transparency animation in CSS

Tags: css

having a slight problem here. I have a background image on the page. I want a div to fade in and 'cover' the image via transparency. It works fine except at the end. The transparency/opacity value should end at 0.8 but once the 7s of transition are done it 'jumps' to full opacity (doesn't remain at 0.8). Here is the css code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from   { opacity: 0.5; }
    to { opacity: 0.8; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from   { opacity: 0.5; }
    to { opacity: 0.8; }
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from   { opacity: 0.5;}
    to { opacity: 0.8; }
}

 #contents {width:900px; height:600px; margin-left:40px; border:groove; background-color: #003; -webkit-animation: fadein 7s; -moz-animation: fadein 7s; animation: fadein 7s; }
```

... I'm obviously missing a hand-brake somewhere .. any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not have any problem. This is the characteristics and disadvantage of using css3 @keyframe, it will returns its original property value after animation. You should instead use the jQuery library of javascript, like this:

```
$("#contents").css("opacity","0.5");
$("#contents").animate({opacity:'0.8'},7000);
```

Or, you can just add this css elements, like this:

```
#contents{opacity:0.8;}
```

Comment: Thanks, added the opacity: 0.8; to the div. Now working fine (pretty obvious when you think about it lol!). Rapid response much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know there's already an answer, but I'm bored at work, so here's a jsfiddle with another concept: http://jsfiddle.net/7MFQX/2/

---

Using jquery it fades in a `<div>` who's opacity is already set via CSS

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `animation-fill-mode:forwards` for your animation. This will ensure the animation doesn't return to it's original value and stops at the end value.